# Unit testing angular-bootstrap $modal

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, angular-ui

I'm having problems trying to write a jasmine unit test for an Angular-Bootstrap `$modal`. The exact error is
`Expected spy open to have been called with [ { templateUrl : '/n/views/consent.html', controller : 'W2ConsentModal as w2modal', resolve : { employee : Function }, size : 'lg' } ] but actual calls were [ { templateUrl : '/n/views/consent.html', controller : 'W2ConsentModal as w2modal', resolve : { employee : Function }, size : 'lg' } ]`

The expected and actual modal options object are the same. What is going on?

#### Controller

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app')
        .controller('W2History', W2History);

    W2History.$inject = ['$scope', '$modal', 'w2Service'];

    function W2History($scope, $modal, w2Service) {
        /* jshint validthis:true */
        var vm = this;
        vm.showModal = showModal;

        function showModal(employee) {
            var modalInstance = $modal.open({
                templateUrl: '/n/views/consent.html',
                controller: 'W2ConsentModal as w2modal',
                resolve: {
                    employee: function () {
                        return employee;
                    }
                },
                size: 'lg'
            });

            modalInstance.result.then(function (didConsent) {
                // code omitted
            });
        }


    }
})();
```

#### Test

```
 describe('W2History controller', function () {
        var controller, scope, modal;

        var fakeModal = {
            result: {
                then: function (confirmCallback, cancelCallback) {
                    //Store the callbacks for later when the user clicks on the OK or Cancel button of the dialog
                    this.confirmCallBack = confirmCallback;
                    this.cancelCallback = cancelCallback;
                }
            },
            close: function (item) {
                //The user clicked OK on the modal dialog, call the stored confirm callback with the selected item
                this.result.confirmCallBack(item);
            },
            dismiss: function (type) {
                //The user clicked cancel on the modal dialog, call the stored cancel callback
                this.result.cancelCallback(type);
            }
        };

        var modalOptions = {
            templateUrl: '/n/views/consent.html',
            controller: 'W2ConsentModal as w2modal',
            resolve: {
                employee: function () {
                    return employee;
                }
            },
            size: 'lg'
        };

        beforeEach(function () {
            module('app');

            inject(function (_$controller_, _$rootScope_, _$modal_) {
                scope = _$rootScope_.$new();                         
                modal = _$modal_;

                spyOn(modal, 'open').and.returnValue(fakeModal);

                controller = _$controller_('W2History', {
                    $scope: scope,
                    $modal: modal,
                    w2Service: w2Srvc
                });

            });

        });

        it('Should correctly show the W2 consent modal', function () {
            var employee = terminatedaccessMocks.getCurrentUserInfo();

            controller.showModal(employee);
            expect(modal.open).toHaveBeenCalledWith(modalOptions);
        });



    });
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try this:

```
describe('W2History controller', function () {
        var controller, scope, modal;

        var fakeModal = {
            result: {
                then: function (confirmCallback, cancelCallback) {
                    //Store the callbacks for later when the user clicks on the OK or Cancel button of the dialog
                    this.confirmCallBack = confirmCallback;
                    this.cancelCallback = cancelCallback;
                }
            },
            close: function (item) {
                //The user clicked OK on the modal dialog, call the stored confirm callback with the selected item
                this.result.confirmCallBack(item);
            },
            dismiss: function (type) {
                //The user clicked cancel on the modal dialog, call the stored cancel callback
                this.result.cancelCallback(type);
            }
        };

        var modalOptions = {
            templateUrl: '/n/views/consent.html',
            controller: 'W2ConsentModal as w2modal',
            resolve: {
                employee: jasmine.any(Function)
            },
            size: 'lg'
        };

        var actualOptions;

        beforeEach(function () {
            module('plunker');

            inject(function (_$controller_, _$rootScope_, _$modal_) {
                scope = _$rootScope_.$new();                         
                modal = _$modal_;

                spyOn(modal, 'open').and.callFake(function(options){
                    actualOptions = options;

                    return fakeModal;
                });

                controller = _$controller_('W2History', {
                    $scope: scope,
                    $modal: modal
                });

            });

        });

        it('Should correctly show the W2 consent modal', function () {
            var employee = { name : "test"};

            controller.showModal(employee);
            expect(modal.open).toHaveBeenCalledWith(modalOptions);
            expect(actualOptions.resolve.employee()).toEqual(employee);
        });
    });
```

[PLUNK](http://plnkr.co/edit/crY61q0haZ5k39tIPYg9?p=preview)

**Explanation**:

We should not expect the actual `resolve.employee` to be the same with the fake `resolve.employee` because `resolve.employee` is a function which returns an employee (in this case the employee is captured in closure). The function could be the same but **at runtime** the returned objects could be different.

The reason your test is failing is the way javascript compares functions. Take a look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hgb15zut/). Anyway, I don't care about this because we should not expect **function implementations**. What we do care about in this case is the `resolve.employee` returns the same object as we pass in:

```
expect(actualOptions.resolve.employee()).toEqual(employee);
```

So the solution here is:
We expect everything except for the `resolve.employee`:

```
var modalOptions = {
                templateUrl: '/n/views/consent.html',
                controller: 'W2ConsentModal as w2modal',
                resolve: {
                    employee: jasmine.any(Function) //don't care about the function as we check it separately.
                },
                size: 'lg'
            };

   expect(modal.open).toHaveBeenCalledWith(modalOptions);
```

Check the `resolve.employee` separately by capturing it first:

```
var actualOptions;

 spyOn(modal, 'open').and.callFake(function(options){
      actualOptions = options; //capture the actual options               
      return fakeModal;
 });

expect(actualOptions.resolve.employee()).toEqual(employee); //Check the returned employee is actually the one we pass in.
```

Comment: So simple! Thanks so much. This was bothering me for a while.

Answer (score 1):

This is a [pass by reference vs pass by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6605640/javascript-by-reference-vs-by-value) issue. The `resolve.employee` anonymous function used in `$modal.open`:

```
var modalInstance = $modal.open({
    templateUrl: '/n/views/consent.html',
    controller: 'W2ConsentModal as w2modal',
    resolve: {
        employee: function () {
            return employee;
        }
    },
    size: 'lg'
});
```

is **not** the same (by reference) as the `resolve.employee` anonymous function in your test:

```
var modalOptions = {
    templateUrl: '/n/views/consent.html',
    controller: 'W2ConsentModal as w2modal',
    resolve: {
        employee: function () {
            return employee;
        }
    },
    size: 'lg'
};
```

Your test should be:

```
resolve: {
    employee: jasmine.any(Function)
}
```

If it's essential that the resolve function be tested, you should expose it somewhere where you can get a reference to the same function in your tests.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however changing my test to use `employee: jasmine.any(Function)` or just `employee: Function` still does not pass the test

Comment: Is your resolve function using the minification protection technique? Mine was and prevent jasmine.any(Function) from working

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this will help you now, but when you spy on something you can get the argument that is passed to the $uibModal.open spy, you can then call that function to test that it returns what is in the resolve method.

```
it('expect resolve to be have metadataid that will return 9999', () => {
            spyOn($uibModal, 'open');
            //add test code here that will call the $uibModal.open
            var spy = <jasmine.Spy>$uibModal.open;
            var args = spy.calls.argsFor(0);
            expect(args[0].resolve.metadataId()).toEqual(9999);
});
```

***** my code is using typescript, but this works for me.**

Answer (score 0):

I have come across the same scenario. I have come across the problem with the below given solution

```
//Function to open export modal
scope.openExportModal();
expect( uibModal.open ).toHaveBeenCalledWith(options);
expect( uibModal.open.calls.mostRecent().args[0].resolve.modalData() ).toEqual(modalData);
```

Hope this may help if you want a quick fix.