# unit test resolve of angular bootstrap modal with johnpapa vm style

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, unit-testing, jasmine

I have created a common `ModalService` and this is used for two different type of dialogs. `CancelDialog` and `ErrorDialog` will be popped up as per parameter passed to service.

i.e This will show an `ErrorDialog`

```
ModalService.openModal('Analysis Error', 'I am Error Type', 'Error');
```

Unit test for `resolve` is failing. Check this [PLUNKER](https://plnkr.co/edit/YkFEMnAanrNXfeYtvY5h?p=preview) for running Unit Test.

This is in file `ModalDialogService.js`. See sample code here:

```
function openCancelModal(title, message, callback) {
  $uibModal.open({
    templateUrl: 'CancelDialog.html',
    controller: 'DialogController',
    controllerAs: 'vm',
    backdrop: 'static',
    size: 'md',
    resolve: {
      message: function() {
        return message;
      },
      title: function() {
        return title;
      },
      callback: function() {
        return callback;
      }
    }
  });
}
```

This is test file `ModalService.spec.js`

```
describe('ModalService', function() {

var $injector;
var $uibModal;

// inject the module of your controller
beforeEach(module('validationApp', function($provide) {
  $uibModal = {
    open: jasmine.createSpy('open')
  };

  $provide.value('$uibModal', $uibModal);
}));

beforeEach(inject(function(_$injector_) {
  $injector = _$injector_;
}));

it('tests that openErrorModal is called', function() {
  var modalService = $injector.get('ModalService');
  modalService.openModal(null, null, "Error");

  expect($uibModal.open).toHaveBeenCalledWith(jasmine.objectContaining({
    controller: "DialogController",
    templateUrl: 'ErrorDialog.html',
    resolve: {
      message: function() {
        return message;
      },
      title: function() {
        return title;
      },
      callback: function() {
        return callback;
      }
    }
  }));
});


it('tests that openCancelModal is called', function() {
  var modalService = $injector.get('ModalService');
  modalService.openModal(null, null, "Cancel");

  expect($uibModal.open).toHaveBeenCalledWith(jasmine.objectContaining({
    controller: "DialogController",
    templateUrl: 'CancelDialog.html'
  }));
});

});
```

Failing Error

```
Expected spy open to have been called with [ <jasmine.objectContaining(Object({ controller: 'DialogController', templateUrl: 'ErrorDialog.html', resolve: Object({ message: Function, title: Function, callback: Function }) }))> ] but actual calls were [ Object({ templateUrl: 'ErrorDialog.html', controller: 'DialogController', controllerAs: 'vm', backdrop: 'static', size: 'md', resolve: Object({ message: Function, title: Function, callback: Function }) }) ].
```

I found this [ANSWER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26853603/unit-testing-angular-bootstrap-modal/26942188) helpful but not able to replicate.
How to cover unit test for `resolve` with `vm` style?

Comment: which method are you trying to test?

Comment: all three `message`, `title` and `callback `.

Comment: I found this answers helpful but not able to replicate. This is testing `resolve` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26853603/unit-testing-angular-bootstrap-modal/26942188

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
fdescribe('ModalService', function () {

    var $injector;
    var $uibModal;
    var actualOptions;

    // inject the module of your controller
    beforeEach(module('validationApp', function ($provide) {
        $uibModal = {
            open: jasmine.createSpy('open').and.callFake(function (options) {
                actualOptions = options;
            })
        };

        $provide.value('$uibModal', $uibModal);
    }));

    beforeEach(inject(function (_$injector_) {
        $injector = _$injector_;
    }));

    it('tests that resolve returns the same values', function () {
        var title = {};
        var message = {};
        var callback = {};

        var modalService = $injector.get('ModalService');
        modalService.openModal(title, message, "Error", callback);

        expect(actualOptions.resolve.title()).toEqual(title);
        expect(actualOptions.resolve.message()).toEqual(message);
        expect(actualOptions.resolve.callback()).toEqual(callback);
    });

});
```

and the [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/tRYO7LjAMuPQTrTJ2PR9?p=preview)

Comment: not sure why but this doesn't shows as covered in coverage reporter. also it conflicts with existing test of `vm.onOk`, `vm.onContinue` & `vm.onDiscard`. It would be great if you can update the plunker with working changes.

Comment: here is the [updated plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/bmpTZsETJeYXSlNzfXH4?p=preview). Coverage report for what? Do you expect that this line `return message;` is actually executed?

Comment: lets discuss ove chat http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125753/discussion-between-ankitd-and-maximus